# What makes a classifier misclassify data?

Tags: classification, supervised-learning

Could it be from the data itself? Or is it because the model can't detect efficiently the similarities between data, or are there other reasons for misclassification?

Comment: In my opinion, the question if far too vague. Is there a problem you are facing in particular?

Comment: As written, this could be read as "misclassify [any] data". In which case, it can occur even if the model is a perfect reflection of the data generating process, so long as the DGP is stochastic / not deterministic. That is, some degree of misclassification is to be expected because of the existence of noise.

Comment: @gung isn't it simply over-fitting?

Comment: @theGD, you can have a perfect classifier that misclassifies some data, if the process is not deterministic. That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 20):

Let's assume you are talking about mis-classification on training data, i.e., difficult to minimize the loss on training data set, no testing data over-fitting problem involved.

You are correct that, in most cases, the mis-classification can coming from "model is too simple" or "the data is too noisy". I would like to give two examples to further illustrate.

1. The model is "too simple" to capture the "patterns in data".

   - The example is shown in the left figure. Suppose we want to use a logistic regression / a line to separate two classes, but the two classes are not linear separable.
   - In this case, there still are "notable patterns in the data", and if we change the model, we may getting better. For example, if we use KNN classifier, instead of logistic regression, we can have very good performance.
2. The data has too much noise, that it is very hard to do the classification task.

   - The example is shown in the right figure, where, if you check the code, you will see two classes are very similar (two classes are 2D Gaussian, the mean is $0.01\times 2$ apart, but the standard deviation for each class is $1.0$ ). It is essentially a very challenging task.

[image: Example datasets, one with two meshed spirals, one with heavily overlapping Gaussian distributions]

Note that the two examples are trivial, since we can visualize the data and the classifier. In the real world, it is not the case, when we have millions of data points and super complicated classifiers.

Code:

```
library(mlbench)
set.seed(0)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
d=mlbench.spirals(500)
plot(d)
lg_fit=glm(d$classes~d$x[,1]+d$x[,2]-1,family=binomial())
abline(0,-lg_fit$coefficients[1]/lg_fit$coefficients[2])

d2=mlbench.2dnormals(500,r=0.01)
plot(d2)
```

Comment: you mentioned KNN, please note that I am talking about classification and not clustering, I mean when we have a training and testing data. What makes me little confused is that for example if we have two types of data which means different features for each data, what makes the classifier mislabel the test data in the testing process? I think this leads me to your second example which means that my data have so much noise and the model is struggling because of that but let's assume that we solved that by feature selection, can still be noise out there even after feature selection ?

Comment: or may be I can think of another reason which that my two types of data are actually sharing similarities in their features and that can "fool" the model, could this be one case somehow ?

Comment: @Sofia693 1. KNN is NOT Kmeans, it is a classification model. 2. I am not really follow your comments.

Comment: I meant if we have two groups (for example 50 autism patients and 50 healthy subjects and the data is extracted from MRI where each subject is represented as a feature vector), I train a classifier and use the Leave One Out technique. Now the model can misclassify the testing subject because of noise (as you mentioned in the secnd example) but we can use feature selection to reduce the noise right ? why does the model still misclassifies the testing subject ? could still be there noise even after feature selection ?

Comment: My second assumption is that the two groups are actually sharing similarities in their feature vectors so the model is really struggling to assign the testing subject to one of the groups.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @hxd1011 (+1).

1. Class imbalance in relative terms or absolute terms. In both cases we build an inadequate representation of the class of interest. Usually the later is more difficult to overcome. (Example reference: [Learning from Imbalanced Data](http://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/he/PDFfiles/ImbalancedLearning.pdf) by He and Garcia)
2. Improper classification criteria. We train our classifier using an inappropriate evaluation function and/or use inappropriate criteria to derive our final solution. Very common issue when using "canned solutions". (Example reference: [Damage Caused by Classification Accuracy and Other Discontinuous Improper Accuracy Scoring Rules](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/03/damage-caused-by-classification.html)  by Harrell)
3. There is no class in reality. We wish there is something there but really there is nothing. Usually domain-expertise steers people away from this but as a new comer this is always an issue. (Example reference: Our daily life. Publication bias probably is an issue here too...)
4. Overfitting. We have a decent model and a decent dataset but we fail to train appropriate building an unrealistic model. Usually this relates to point 2. (Extra-points for under-fitting!) (Example reference: [The Problem of Overfitting](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f65e/e7b52912f8485dc0411a40ccebf5f3f2afef.pdf) by Hawkings)
5. Concept drift. Things change and we don't retrain. Our classifier has excellent performance in our "Christmas sales" marketing sample - yeah, using this model in July probably will be a pain...(Example reference: [A Survey on Concept Drift Adaptation](http://www.win.tue.nl/~mpechen/publications/pubs/Gama_ACMCS_AdaptationCD_accepted.pdf) by Gama et al.)
6. Data leakage / Magic features. We train from information that will be unavailable at the time of prediction. Common when having event/time-series like data. (Example reference: [Leakage in Data Mining: Formulation, Detection, and Avoidance](http://dstillery.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Leakage-in-Data-Mining-Formulation-Detection-and-Avoidance.pdf) by Kaufman et al.)

Comment: I don't understand point 3. The question assumes some notion of a "class" in order to have a classifier that is misclassifying some data. Do you mean that the labeling is inconsistent (the "class" is poorly defined)? Or that the features do not contain any information relevant to the classification task?

Comment: @CharlesStaats: "the features do not contain any information relevant to the classification task" is a failure of the second kind, "improper classification criteria".

Comment: Do you think poor labels would fall into 2, or does it merit its separate entry?

Comment: @CharlesStaats: Assuming "*some notion of class*" does not mean that it actually exists and/or if it can supported by the data at hand. That is why domain expertise is extremely helpful in these cases; it helps us distinguish between a "real problem" and trying to "fit noise". There are cases where the labels reflect a hypothesis (eg. potential to develop a disease caused by a random mutation) rather than a measurable notion (eg. patient has the disease caused by a random mutation).

Comment: @Jonas: This is a good point; I think that mislabelling should be a separate entry. It could potentially associated with the point about "data is too noisy" raised by hxd1011.